# MODIS products reprojection problem

Tags: python, gdal, modis

I am working with Modis Data (MOD02, MOD11, MOD03, MOD35).
In particular I am looking for a solution to reproject the subdatasets below, into albers equal. Because I am using NLCD dataset which uses albers.(`PROJ4: +proj=aea +lat_1=29.5 +lat_2=45.5 +lat_0=23 +lon_0=-96 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs`)  area in 1000 m resolution. I will run a model for whole USA so I thats why I chose Albers.

Can somebody help me? By the way I am aware of the MRT Swath but I want to do this in Python environment.

So far I tried this but there was shifts in the pixels. (Alignment problems).

```
gdalwarp -tr 1000 1000 -of GTIFF -tps -t_srs "+proj=aea +lat_1=29.5 +lat_2=45.5 +lat_0=23  +lon_0=-96 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs” -r cubic 'HDF4_EOS:EOS_SWATH:
"MOD021KM.A2007181.1750.005.2010199133141.hdf”:MODIS_SWATH_Type_L1B:EV_250_Aggr1km_RefSB’ x.tif
```

This one works for the MOD021KM but I couldn't work it out for the rest. 
I am confused.

These are the subdatasets that I want to extract as geotiffs.

```
HDF4_EOS:EOS_SWATH:"MOD021KM.A2007157.1700.005.2010197153031.hdf":MODIS_SWATH_Type_L1B:EV_250_Aggr1km_RefSB
HDF4_EOS:EOS_SWATH:"MOD021KM.A2007157.1700.005.2010197153031.hdf":MODIS_SWATH_Type_L1B:EV_500_Aggr1km_RefSB
HDF4_EOS:EOS_SWATH:"MOD03.A2007157.1700.005.2010196183307.hdf":MODIS_Swath_Type_GEO:SensorZenith
HDF4_EOS:EOS_SWATH:"MOD03.A2007157.1700.005.2010196183307.hdf":MODIS_Swath_Type_GEO:SolarZenith
HDF4_EOS:EOS_SWATH:"MOD11_L2.A2007157.1700.005.2007158222249.hdf":MOD_Swath_LST:LST
HDF4_EOS:EOS_SWATH:"MOD11_L2.A2007157.1700.005.2007158222249.hdf":MOD_Swath_LST:View_angle
HDF4_EOS:EOS_SWATH:"MOD35_L2.A2007157.1700.005.2010197153939.hdf":mod35:Cloud_Mask
```

Comment: What do you mean by:  I couldn't work it out for the rest ? Do you get error messages, or is the result misplaced?

Comment: Hi I appreciate the fast comment. I can do it with MOD02 product even if it is little bit of shifted. But MOD03, MOD35 and MOD11 I get this error: Creating output file that is 0P x 0L.
ERROR 1: Attempt to create 0x0 dataset is illegal,sizes must be larger than zero.

Comment: What you want to do is not simple and hard to do with Python, mostly because of the [bowtie effect](http://mcst.gsfc.nasa.gov/forums/images-seem-distorted-edges-scans-why-and-what-can-be-done). Either you code the correction up yourself, or you use the NASA codes.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this problem as well a few years back. From researching the issue on osgeo.org (issue #805), the consensus from the gdal team was that the MODIS sinusoidal projection spheroid is defined incorrectly(But corrected for in MRT) which resulted in a shift when using gdal_warp(or any tool that is PROJ4 based). The problem is solved by explicitly setting the -s_srs in gdal_warp. i.e.

```
-s_srs "+proj=sinu +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6371007.181 +b=6371007.181 +units=m +no_defs"
```

And for performance comparison, using gdal based tools to mosaic and reproject MODIS data resulted in a decrease in time by a factor of 22 compared to the MRT tool